# Deploy web project on tomcat 6?

Tags: tomcat, deployment

I deployed project to tomcat 6.0 from myEclipe.
Error: Deployment failure on Tomcat 6.x. Could not copy all resources to /Volumes/DATA/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/project. If a file is locked, you can wait until the lock times out to redeploy, or stop the server and redeploy, or manually remove the deployment at /Volumes/DATA/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/project

How to fix it? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this error usually means that eclipse wants to delete a file or directory and windows won't let it. This is usually because tomcat is still running, or there is a command prompt or explorer window open in the deployment directory or one of its subdirectories.

Use Windows Task Manager to verify that tomcat is not still running, and make sure you don't have any command prompts or explorer windows open in the deployment directory.

Comment: Sorry i never used mac,only windows.